# Is it possible to print to the Report window in the Info view?

Tags: python

I wonder if it is currently possible to print or send messages to the Report window in the Info view? this would be quite useful sometimes.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

We can always use an operator's [`report`](https://www.blender.org/api/blender_python_api_current/bpy.types.Operator.html#bpy.types.Operator.report) method. Running the following operator:

```
class RENDER_OT_test(bpy.types.Operator):
    bl_idname = 'render.oha_test'
    bl_label = 'Test'
    bl_options = {'REGISTER', 'UNDO'}

    def execute(self, context):
        self.report({'INFO'}, 'Printing report to Info window.')
        return {'FINISHED'}
```

prints this in the Info window:

[image: Info window]

The color depends on the type enum: `INFO` gets green, `WARNING` light red, and `ERROR` dark red. I don't see reference to any direct output to Info window, other than this method.

Comment: i made this snippet to demo a problem i've experienced: https://gist.github.com/zeffii/5734884  , say I try to call this operator from a place in a script using `bpy.ops.render.oha_test()` i get `Undefined Type: Printing report to Info window.

{'FINISHED'}` and there is no printing to the report window..

Comment: When the enumeration type is only `INFO`, `WARNING` or `ERROR`, the message is prefixed accordingly (e.g. "`Info: ...`"). But if we add `DEBUG`, the prefix turns to "`Undefined Type: ...`". Maybe we're dealing with a little quirk (bug?) in the C function related to flag-reading. Gotta read the source to make sure, but I don't think it's an error. (and `report` doesn't output to report area if executed on a Python interpreter area)

Comment: I don't think multiple values were intended to work, just use one value. They are more like importance levels where `DEBUG` is the lowest and `ERROR` is the highest.

Comment: @brecht I don't know how it's supposed to be used, as there's no documentation. Just trying combination and it just works. And only specifying `DEBUG` outputs nothing, either in shell, Info's report area or header.

Comment: I don't know if combinations should be allowed, but they were not really intended in the design, so maybe something should be fixed in Blender. That's why I suggest to change the example to use only 1 value.

Comment: Oh, the code in `blenkernel/intern/report.c` uses `switch` instead of bitwise ops. That explains...

Comment: OK, thanks guys. The takeaway here is once the script is running it is reasonably easy to send messages to the info window. example: https://gist.github.com/zeffii/5735019

Comment: @brecht Ah yes, it does nothing. Combining `DEBUG` and other type suppresses output to Info area's header, though, which led me to think it has some use :) I concede that it's probably unintended.

Comment: I tried the sample but I cant get message in the info view..

`import bpy

class RENDER_OT_test(bpy.types.Operator): bl_idname = 'render.oha1_test' bl_label = 'Test' bl_options = {'REGISTER', 'UNDO'} def execute(self, context): self.report({'INFO'}, 'Printing report to Info window.') return {'FINISHED'} bpy.utils.register_class(RENDER_OT_test)`
# test call to the newly defined operator
`bpy.ops.render.oha1_test()`

Comment: After running the script, execute the operator as `bpy.ops.render.oha1_test` in Python console or as **Test** in spacebar-menu. Works for me.

Answer (score 11):

I needed to display a notification message *when running a script in the Text Editor* by hitting the **'Run Script'** button. For exactly this purpose I have [found a hack](https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/96724/8282) that works, even if this is not the preferred way :)

```
import bpy

def oops(self, context):
    self.layout.label(text="You have done something you shouldn't do!")

bpy.context.window_manager.popup_menu(oops, title="Error", icon='ERROR')
```

[image]

Comment: with newer version of blender 2.9x use self.layout.label(text="You have done something you shouldn't do!")

Answer (score -3):

This should be the code: to get popup in mouse event use ERROR instead INFO. 
see [report](https://docs.blender.org/api/blender_python_api_current/bpy.types.Operator.html#bpy.types.Operator.report)
-'INFO' is lower and 'ERROR_OUT_OF_MEMORY' is highest level of error type.

```
def yourfunction(context):
    whatever the function 

class RENDER_OT_test(bpy.types.Operator):
    bl_idname = 'render.oha_test'
    bl_label = 'Test'
    bl_options = {'REGISTER', 'UNDO'}

    def execute(self, context):
        try:
            yourfunction(context)
            return {'FINISHED'}
        except:
            self.report({'INFO'}, 'Printing report to Info window.')
            return {'CANCELLED'}
```

Comment: basically is the already accepted solution of 4 years ago...

Comment: The accepted answer doesn't work without try condition in Blender 2.79 and the return statement and code blocks are clarified here.