# Is it possible to print message to the info view?

Tags: python

Is it possible to print message to the info view?

I used Mac OS,Blender2.6.7.
thank you.

Comment: Welcome to the site. :) this has already been asked and answered [here](http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/717/is-it-possible-to-print-to-the-report-window-in-the-info-view)