# Suppress output of Python operators (bpy.ops.*)

Tags: python

Every time the `bpy.ops.remove_doubles()` operator is used, it outputs to my terminal (where I called Blender from).  How can I suppress this output?

The code is:

```
bpy.ops.object.mode_set(mode='EDIT')
bpy.ops.mesh.select_all(action='TOGGLE')
bpy.ops.mesh.remove_doubles()
```

and the undesired output is:

> Info: Removed 48 vertices

Comment: I don't know how to suppress it or if it's even possible, but I believe that message is generated by the `report` method (stuff will appear in stdout every time something is displayed in the info panel) See [this related post](http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/717/is-it-possible-to-print-to-the-report-window-in-the-info-view).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Python can temporarily redirect the `stdout`, this is ideal since you may not want to suppress output for _all_ scripts, just selectively silence some operations.

eg:

```
import bpy

import io
from contextlib import redirect_stdout

stdout = io.StringIO()
with redirect_stdout(stdout):
    bpy.ops.mesh.remove_doubles()
```

If you want you can read the output back out or use it however you like.

```
stdout.seek(0)
output = stdout.read()
print("Report was %r" % output)
```

If you want to redirect both stdout and stderr.

```
import bpy

import io
from contextlib import redirect_stdout, redirect_stderr

output = io.StringIO()
with redirect_stdout(output), redirect_stderr(output):
    bpy.ops.some.operator_that_may_print_text()
```

Comment: This doesn't work for `bpy.ops.wm` Could you help me out with this?

Comment: This does not work with bpy.os.render. See Marc Morcos' answer for that.

Answer (score 3):

To filter the shell output of Blender you can start it via command line using a pipe with *sed* (Linux / OSX) or *findstr* (Windows). We can use *sed* or *findstr* to omit every line that starts with `Info`.

Linux / OSX:

```
blender 2>&1 | grep --line-buffered -v '^Info'
```

Windows:

```
blender.exe 2>&1 | findstr /v /b "Info"
```

*findstr* on Windows doesn't seem to have a similar option like `--line-buffered`. You could [install grep for Windows](http://gnuwin32.sourceforge.net/packages/grep.htm) though.

If you want to mute Blender all together preventing it from printing anything you can do this too.

Linux / OSX:

```
blender > /dev/null 2>&1
```

Windows:

```
blender 2>&1 > NUL
```

Comment: Cool!  I wouldn't have thought of that.  I guess the only disadvantage is the output (which I do care about) is not displayed until I quit Blender.

Comment: I updated my answer to account for realtime output (I hope).

Comment: I tried the command above (blender 2>&1 | grep --line-buffered -v '^Info'), but again, it displayed no output at all until I closed Blender, at which point, it correctly suppressed all the lines starting with 'Info'.

Comment: You can verify this behavior by opening a new Blender file, then go to Text Editor, then entering: print("Info - don't display"); print("Hello - display this"), then running the script.

Comment: Hm, in that case try the other answer :(

Comment: blender 2>&1 | grep --line-buffered -v '^Info'

Works like a charm. Thank you, @Maccesch!

Answer (score 3):

This worked for me (at least for bpy.ops.render) . https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5081657/how-do-i-prevent-a-c-shared-library-to-print-on-stdout-in-python
It makes a context manager you can use to block the output of specific lines.

```
import os
import sys
from contextlib import contextmanager

@contextmanager
def stdout_redirected(to=os.devnull):
    '''
    import os

    with stdout_redirected(to=filename):
        print("from Python")
        os.system("echo non-Python applications are also supported")
    '''
    fd = sys.stdout.fileno()

    ##### assert that Python and C stdio write using the same file descriptor
    ####assert libc.fileno(ctypes.c_void_p.in_dll(libc, "stdout")) == fd == 1

    def _redirect_stdout(to):
        sys.stdout.close() # + implicit flush()
        os.dup2(to.fileno(), fd) # fd writes to 'to' file
        sys.stdout = os.fdopen(fd, 'w') # Python writes to fd

    with os.fdopen(os.dup(fd), 'w') as old_stdout:
        with open(to, 'w') as file:
            _redirect_stdout(to=file)
        try:
            yield # allow code to be run with the redirected stdout
        finally:
            _redirect_stdout(to=old_stdout) # restore stdout.
                                            # buffering and flags such as
                                            # CLOEXEC may be different
```

Then just use as follows:

```
with stdout_redirected():
     bpy.ops.render.render(write_still=True)
```

Comment: This should be the accepted answer!

Answer (score 2):

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6796492/python-temporarily-redirect-stdout-stderr) looks to be exactly what you need. This process would work well for redirecting `stdout` and/or `stderr` to `/dev/null` when you're about to display something that you don't want to see.

Essentially, point the current references to /dev/null, which will make output go away:

`devnull = open(os.devnull, 'w')`

`sys.stdout, sys.stderr = devnull, devnull`

...then point them back to stdout and stderr when you're done, which will restore normal output:

`sys.stdout = self.__stdout__`

`sys.stderr = self.__stderr__`

Comment: Note: `sys` *already* contains the original values for `stdout` and `stderr`. You do *not* have to save them. To restore: `sys.stdout = sys.__stdout__`. The same is true in many other cases. Also `/dev/null` is not valid python syntax.

Comment: I see, but in the [Python docs](http://docs.python.org/3.3/library/sys.html) udner `sys.__stdout__`, it says "the preferred way to do this is to explicitly save the previous stream before replacing it, and restore the saved object."

Comment: While this will work, it would be better to temporarily override stdout, see: http://blender.stackexchange.com/a/34218/55

Comment: This doesn't work for `bpy.ops.wm`.