# Dump Scene object Information To console or String for debugging purposes

Tags: python, blender-internal-render-engine, blend-files, scene

A very simple question on how to dump `bpy.context.scene` information using python script to blender console or a string so I can use to debug.

I have tried to serialize the object using pickle and json dump with no success.
Serializing seems to not work here for some reason.

> Note to downvoters: Please atleast leave a constructive comment why you feel this question needs to be downvoted. If you dont know the answer move on.

Comment: I think you can use this http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/34217/how-to-redirect-output-from-bpy-ops and Python pretty print.

Comment: I tried the method you suggested, but it only yields `bpy.data.scenes['Scene']` as text

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had the need to do something similar recently, and here is a very brief solution that I attempted, hopefully it can be helpful:

1. Create a script at the same location with your target `.blend` file named something like `script.py`:

```
import bpy
# Use bpy.context.scene.objects.keys() to get the name of objects

with open('output.txt', 'w+') as the_file:
    the_file.write(', '.join(bpy.context.scene.objects.keys()))
```

2. Execute blender in background for the target file and run the script: In command line, use `blender -b filename.blend -P script.py` to run blender in background and execute the script on the scene.

This script will dump all object names in the scene into a file named "**output.txt**".