# Blender script run print to console

Tags: scripting, command-line

How can I run some script and have print result in console window? Now I have these results only in System Console Window.
[image]

Answer (score 13):

**Override print method.**

---

Been investigating a number of ways to do this.  Possibly the simplest is to  override the print in your scripts.  Below is designed to `from somewhere import print` and writes all print non keyword arguments to open consoles in same screen.

```
import bpy
from bpy import context

import builtins as __builtin__

def console_print(*args, **kwargs):
    for a in context.screen.areas:
        if a.type == 'CONSOLE':
            c = {}
            c['area'] = a
            c['space_data'] = a.spaces.active
            c['region'] = a.regions[-1]
            c['window'] = context.window
            c['screen'] = context.screen
            s = " ".join([str(arg) for arg in args])
            for line in s.split("\n"):
                bpy.ops.console.scrollback_append(c, text=line)

def print(*args, **kwargs):
    """Console print() function."""

    console_print(*args, **kwargs) # to py consoles
    __builtin__.print(*args, **kwargs) # to system console

print("print me to console")
print("and me\n and me", "and me\nI'm:", print)
```

[image: ![enter image description here]

My attempts at redirecting stdio have failed and often lock up a console. Will get back to this later with better links, but there is a lot of console code to fiddle around with ...  `console_python.py` `bl_operators/console.py` and the mathviz addon code.

EDIT: See [Dubplicate Question Answer](https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/78332/15543) on handling stdio redirecting.

Comment: This can also be improved by writing the script to a seperated `pyconsole.py` file, which is in the path of `sys.path` (e.g. `%APPDATA%\Blender Foundation\Blender\<version>\scripts\addons`) in Blender, and then use `from pyconsole import print` in the script.