# How to print colored text to blender python console?

Tags: python

I prefer using the Python Console Editor over System Console.
In System Console you can print colored text with ANSI escape sequences (I learned this via https://stackoverflow.com/questions/287871/how-to-print-colored-text-to-the-terminal).
For example, the 2 lines below print "Colored text" in red in the System Console:

```
CSI = "\x1B["
print(CSI+"31;40m" + "Colored Text" + CSI + "0m")
```

How do I make this work in python console?
Thanks in advance

Comment: IIRC this has been asked before and it is not possible.  Can print in red (error color) with `bpy.ops.console.scrollback_append(text="Coloured Text", type='ERROR')`  (4 choices output , input, info, error) Somewhat Related https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/93728/blender-script-run-print-to-console

Comment: Try using something such as IDLE, eDEX-UI, or Geany.