# Print message to Info in Blender 2.8

Tags: python

I feel like this should be easier to find. Aug '19, I've searched google and stack with no easy answers.

In **Blender 2.8**:

I'm looking for the code similar to `Print("MY_MESSAGE")` into the `Info` window. Obviously it's easy to use `Print('...')` into the `System Console` - sys console unrelated to this question.

I'm looking for any sample code I can *literally* copy paste into my Blender `Text Editor` window and run with results.

tldr: one-liner print shit to `Info` window, pls how?!

Comment: Here you go: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/717/is-it-possible-to-print-to-the-report-window-in-the-info-view

Comment: That's like the first thing off google for this question. Not sure if 2.8, or because I don't understand how to correctly use that code, or other reasons, but it does not work for me

Comment: Again, for what seems (to me) to be a very basic question - in hack-y script-kiddie code - there seems to be a lack of an easily implemented answer that can be quickly found. I'm looking for a copy-pasta hello world.

Comment: Check https://docs.blender.org/api/blender_python_api_current/bpy.types.Operator.html to see how the operator must be called.

Answer (score 3):

*For all the lazy people, who don't like reading the API on how to register and call an operator:*

```
import bpy

class RENDER_OT_test(bpy.types.Operator):
    """Tooltip"""
    bl_idname = "render.custom_test"
    bl_label = "Test"

    def execute(self, context):
        self.report({'INFO'}, 'Printing report to Info window.')
        return {'FINISHED'}

def register():
    bpy.utils.register_class(RENDER_OT_test)

def unregister():
    bpy.utils.unregister_class(RENDER_OT_test)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    register()
```

Run the script, press <kbd>F3</kbd> to open up the search menu, type `Test`and press <kbd>Enter</kbd>.

<sup>No additional link to prevent lazy people from getting even more lazy.</sup>

Comment: Changed my mind: [How to script add-on info and warnings?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/96800/31447)

Comment: Thank you for this reply! This works for me. The bit that really helped was the `F3` -> `Test` -> `Enter`, since I am new to Blender. This still seems far more complex than the simple `Print(...)` statement I hoped for

Comment: It also appears that this must be run via the `F3...` combo in order for the info message to appear. I can't seem to make this work from purely from code, when using the `Run Script` button or `alt+p` hotkey.

Comment: Correct, that is by design. The message intentionally only appears when **the user** is calling something **from within the UI** (Search Menu, Button, Part of another operator call and whatnot). If that's too complex for your case, use a `print("fat flying pigs")` @fat_flying_pigs. However, in case you'd like to build an Add-on, using *operators* is the way to go anyway. Read: [How to create a custom UI?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/57332/31447).

Comment: I knew blender was bad, like "pressing b in file select literally opens a bounding box" bad, but I never knew it was "you literally can't print to the designated console" bad

Comment: You can `print()` to the console @AndyRay Question is about how to print into the *Info Area*...