# Popup during an import as a result of an exception

Tags: python, add-on

Is there an example of a popup window been spawned as part of another process?

In my case I want to write an importer that will invoke a popup if an image path can not be found and allow the user to browse to another path, this path can then be used to search for the image at a different location.  When the file first cannot be found, the main addon raises an exception, I want this exception to cause the popup.

I don't know addons well, but the popup itself is not a menu option just something that is a result of another menu option not been able to complete.

Comment: Prefered way is to use `Operator.report()` method (Popups blocking the user interface, which is against Blender's UI paradigm): https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/717/is-it-possible-to-print-to-the-report-window-in-the-info-view Also have look into: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/73286/how-to-call-a-confirmation-dialog-box/73548#73548

Comment: It is not clear how to input something to an Operator.report, and have that value be available to the whole of the blender project.

Comment: You can use a PropertyGroup: https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/57332/31447