# Customize Info Editor

Tags: python, interface, customization

Is there a way to extend the range of commands what actually Info Editor logs? It seems there are actions with records on the log and actions without any logs.

For example: If I create a box object it results:

```
bpy.ops.mesh.primitive_cube_add(size=2, enter_editmode=False, align='WORLD', location=(0, 0, 0), scale=(1, 1, 1))
```

But if I select the same object or I hovering the cursor on the location property and press I key (animate the location) there is no log.

Comment: yes some commands are not logged but you can log anything whenever you like using an operators [`report`](https://www.blender.org/api/blender_python_api_current/bpy.types.Operator.html#bpy.types.Operator.report) function

Comment: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/717/is-it-possible-to-print-to-the-report-window-in-the-info-view

Comment: Could you be more specific? I can't rewrite that linked code according to my needs. Thanks!